# Как сделать нормальное поисковое поле?

Tags: c#, uwp

Здравствуйте!
У меня на фрейме есть `AutoSuggestBox`. На событие изменения текста навешен такой код:

```
        private void AsbSearch_TextChanged(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            _timer.Stop();
            _timer.Start();
        }
```

Интервал у таймера равен 100 миллисекундам. Вот код, выполняемый при тике:

```
        private void _timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
        {
            _timer.Stop();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(AsbSearch.Text) || AsbSearch.Text == " ")
            {
                return;
            }
            AsbSearch_QuerySubmitted(AsbSearch, null);
        }
```

Так вот, теперь все это плохо работает, поскольку поиск начинается несколько раз при вводе одного слова(быстрого ввода), причем первый поиск начинается примерно после ввода 3-4 символов. 
Как мне решить эту проблему? Можно конечно оставить начало поиска лишь на нажатие Enter-а или соответствующей кнопки, но это нежелательно.

**Обновление**

По сути мне надо выходить из `AsbSearch_QuerySubmitted(AsbSearch, null);` при изменении запроса. Но как это сделать? Пробовал использование булевой переменной с периодической проверкой, но нет, все точно также.

Comment: А зачем вам таймер? Что он такого полезного делает? Если вам надо выходить из метода при изменении запроса, то сохраняйте предыдущий запрос в переменной и потом сравнивайте, в случае несовпадения => выход. Почему так не сделать?

Comment: @Bulson, Мда, а ведь до последнего я и не додумался. Сейчас попробую, спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А если с таймером, то так пытались или иначе?

```
private bool _searching = false;

...

private void _timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
  _timer.Stop();
  //У нас уже идет поиск, выходим, даже текст смотреть не будем:
  if (_searching) return;

  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(AsbSearch.Text) || AsbSearch.Text == " ")
  {
    return;
  }
  //Устанавливаем флаг того. что поиск начат:
  _searching = true;
  //Ищем:
  AsbSearch_QuerySubmitted(AsbSearch, null);
  //Поиск закончен....
  _searching = false;
```

}

UPD: Вариант без таймера:

```
private string _PrevText = string.Empty;
...
private void AsbSearch_TextChanged(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs args)
{
  //Текущий текст для поиска:
  string _CurrentText = AsbSearch.Text;

  //Если предыдущий текст для поиска уже пустой, то можем искать текущий:
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_PrevText))
  {
    //Запоминаем в переменную предыдущего поиска значение для текущего поиска
    _PrevText = _CurrentText;
    //Ищем:
    AsbSearch_QuerySubmitted(AsbSearch, null);
    //После того, как поиск выполнен, очищаем переменную предыдущего поиска.
    _PrevText = string.Empty;
  }
}
```

Comment: Вот что-то вроде <code>_searching</code> было, но не перед проверкой текста поискового поля, поскольку тогда поиск будет проводиться по старому запросу, а не по новому.

Comment: Спасибо, я опробовал ваш пример, и он подходит. Однако лично я нашел более удобным такой код:
<code>

Comment: Случайно нажал на Enter.

Вот так код

<pre><code>    if (args.CheckCurrent())
            {
                await Task.Delay(100);
                if (!args.CheckCurrent()) return;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(AsbSearch.Text) || AsbSearch.Text == " ")
                {
                    _rootPage.PageDirectoryQuery = string.Empty;
                    ShowContacts();
                    return;
                }
                AsbSearch_QuerySubmitted(null, null);
            }</code></pre>

Comment: Ну как вам удобнее, так и работайте, вам же это использовать, не мне  )) Хорошо, что нашли решение!

Answer (score 1):

Вот нашел инфу о `AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs.CheckCurrent`. И мне это в принципе подходит, поэтому вот новый код, выполняемый при изменении текста в поисковом поле:

```
            if (args.CheckCurrent())
            {
                await Task.Delay(100);
                if (!args.CheckCurrent()) return;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(AsbSearch.Text) || AsbSearch.Text == " ")
                {
                    //код
                    return;
                }
                AsbSearch_QuerySubmitted(null, null);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Зачем тут вообще таймер? Поисковое поле должно работать как поисковое поле без всяких таймеров и засыпаний потока. Ввели минимальное кол-во символов, необходимое для поиска - отправили запрос, получили в ответ список - заменили `ItemsSource` у `AutoSuggestBox`. Ввели еще один символ - отправили запрос, получили новый список - снова заменили `ItemsSource` у `AutoSuggestBox`. Работает проще некуда.

Comment: Таймер нужен. Пока пользователь быстро вводит текст, запрос не отправляется. Как только пользователь сделал паузу, значит он либо ждёт подсказку, либо полностью завершил ввод - отправляем запрос. Вот для засекания паузы и нужен таймер.

Comment: Гугл делает паузу? Яндекс делает? Браузеры делают? Что за выдумка про паузу? Поиск должен работать максимально быстро. Особенно если речь о поисковых подсказках. 
Если не хотите чтобы поиск срабатывал при вводе первого символа, а начинался только после двух, то в `AsbSearch_TextChanged` надо просто проверять сколько символов введено. А специально замедлять реакцию - это антипаттерн.

Comment: @MakeMakeluv В том то и дело, что тут нет поисковых подсказок. По крайней мере пока что.